# isFieldsTouched turn "true" when use setFieldsValue antd form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to check user type in form with isFieldsTouched but when the first render, i fill data to the form and isFieldsTouched turn to "true", even i'm not touch at all. How can I fix this.

My version:
antd:4.21.5,
react:18.2.0

demo:[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-gould-d3j4hg?file=/src/App.tsx)

I want isFieldsTouched false when I setFieldsValue. Anyone have solution. Thank alot

Comment: maybe you want to use `initialValues` to set the default values instead of using `setFieldsValue`

Comment: Use form.setFields to set value and touched to false `form.setFields([{ name: 'note', value: 'Hello world!', touched:false }])`

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique thanks for advice, but when i pass touched:false to setFields, the isFieldsTouched always false enven i type something on input field, that not behavior i want

Comment: Remove second `useEffect`

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique it is still false when i type on input. can you gave me an examaple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to detect if field is `touched` is wrong because useEffect dependency never changes. Assuming that you want to detect if field is `touched` or not after you set the field values. There are 2 ways to solve this problem.

**First Approach: (Use `onFieldsChange`) and passing trigger='onFocus' in `Form.Item`**

You can pass onFieldsChange to `Form` component and check the `changedValues` array if required field is touched or not. Note that we pass trigger='onFocus' that will trigger onFieldsChange otherwise onFieldsChange will only be called when any field value changes.

Remember `changedValues` is an array. Second value of value is an object containing following fields:

- name (Your field name is `note`. so name will be ['note'])
- value
- errors
- warnings
- touched
- validating

```
import { Form, Input } from "antd";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [touch, setTouch] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({ note: "aaaaa" });
  }, [form]);

  console.log(touch);

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      onFieldsChange={(changedValue, allFields) => {
        changedValue.forEach((value) => {
          if (value.name.toString() === "note") {
            setTouch(value.touched ?? false);
          }
        });
      }}
    >
      <Form.Item name="note" trigger='onFocus'>
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Second Approach: (Use onFocus)**

```
import { Form, Input } from "antd";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [touch, setTouch] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({ note: "aaaaa" });
  }, [form]);

  console.log(touch);

  return (
    <Form form={form}>
      <Form.Item name="note">
        <Input onFocus={() => setTouch(true)} />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Use first approach if your field value can be changed by any external field otherwise use second approach.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: the solution one solve my problem. thank you so much